# Issues setting lifetimes in functions of Traits

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a trait `Atom` that has many associated types, of which one is an owned version `OP` and the other is a borrow version `O` of essentially the same data. I have a function `to_pow_view` that creates a view from an owned version and I have an equality operator.

Below is an attempt:

```rust
pub trait Atom: PartialEq {
    // variants truncated for this example
    type P<'a>: Pow<'a, R = Self>;
    type OP: OwnedPow<R = Self>;
}

pub trait Pow<'a>: Clone + PartialEq {
    type R: Atom;
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum AtomView<'a, R: Atom> {
    Pow(R::P<'a>),
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum OwnedAtom<R: Atom> {
    Pow(R::OP),
}

pub trait OwnedPow {
    type R: Atom;

    fn some_mutable_fn(&mut self);

    fn to_pow_view<'a>(&'a self) -> <Self::R as Atom>::P<'a>;

    // compiler said I should add 'a: 'b
    fn test<'a: 'b, 'b>(&'a mut self, other: <Self::R as Atom>::P<'b>) {
        if self.to_pow_view().eq(&other) {
            self.some_mutable_fn();
        }
    }
}

impl<R: Atom> OwnedAtom<R> {
    // compiler said I should add 'a: 'b, why?
    pub fn eq<'a: 'b, 'b>(&'a self, other: AtomView<'b, R>) -> bool {
        let a: AtomView<'_, R> = match self {
            OwnedAtom::Pow(p) => {
                let pp = p.to_pow_view();
                AtomView::Pow(pp)
            }
        };

        match (&a, &other) {
            (AtomView::Pow(l0), AtomView::Pow(r0)) => l0 == r0,
        }
    }
}

// implementation

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct Rep {}

impl Atom for Rep {
    type P<'a> = PowD<'a>;
    type OP = OwnedPowD;
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct PowD<'a> {
    data: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> Pow<'a> for PowD<'a> {
    type R = Rep;
}

struct OwnedPowD {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl OwnedPow for OwnedPowD {
    type R = Rep;

    fn some_mutable_fn(&mut self) {
        todo!()
    }

    fn to_pow_view<'a>(&'a self) -> <Self::R as Atom>::P<'a> {
        PowD { data: &self.data }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

This code gives the error:

```
27 |     fn test<'a: 'b, 'b>(&'a mut self, other: <Self::R as Atom>::P<'b>) {
   |                     -- lifetime `'b` defined here
28 |         if self.to_pow_view().eq(&other) {
   |            ------------------
   |            |
   |            immutable borrow occurs here
   |            argument requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'b`
29 |             self.some_mutable_fn();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

I expect this to work, since the immutable borrow should be dropped right after the `eq` function evaluates.

Something in the setting of the lifetimes is wrong in this code, already in the equality function `eq`: I would expect that there is no relation between `'a` and `'b`; they should just live long enough to do the comparison. However, the compiler tells me that I should add `'a: 'b` and I do not understand why. The same thing happened for the function `test`.

These problems lead me to believe that the lifetimes in `to_pow_view` are wrong, but no modification I tried made it work (except for removing the `'a` lifetime on `&'a self`, but then the `OwnedPowD` does not compile anymore).

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d342ebc94394d1e535b2f89d9303215b)

Can someone help understand what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the point: you constrained `Pow` to be `PartialEq`. However, `PartialEq` is `PartialEq<Self>`. In other words, **`Pow<'a>` only implements `PartialEq<Pow<'a>>` for the same `'a`**.

This is usually the case for any type with lifetime and `PartialEq`, so why does it always work but not here?

It usually works because if we compare `T<'a> == T<'b>`, the compiler can shrink the lifetimes to the shortest of the two and compare that.

However, `Pow` is a trait. Traits are *invariant* over their lifetime, in other words, it must stay exactly as is, not longer nor shorter. This is because they may be used with invariant types, for example `Cell<&'a i32>`. Here's an example of how it could be exploited if this was allowed:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Evil<'a> {
    v: Cell<&'a i32>,
}

impl PartialEq for Evil<'_> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        // We asserted the lifetimes are the same, so we can do that.
        self.v.set(other.v.get());
        false
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Evil { v: Cell::new(&123) };
    {
        let has_short_lifetime = 456;
        _ = foo == Evil { v: Cell::new(&has_short_lifetime) };
    }
    // Now `foo` contains a dangling reference to `has_short_lifetime`!
    dbg!(foo.v.get());
}
```

The above code does not compile, because `Evil` is invariant over `'a`, but if it would, it would contain UB in safe code. For that reason, traits, that may contain types such as `Evil`, are also invariant over their lifetimes.

Because of that, the compiler cannot shrink the lifetime of `other`. It can shrink the lifetime of `self.to_pow_view()` (in `test()`, `eq()` is similar), because it doesn't really shrink it, it just picks a shorter lifetime for `to_pow_view()`'s `self`. But because `PartialEq` is only implemented for types with the same lifetime, it means that the `Pow` resulting from `self.to_pow_view()` must have the same lifetime of `other`. Because of that, (a) `'a` must be greater than or equal to `'b`, so we can pick `'b` out of it, and (b) by comparing, we borrow `self` for potentially whole `'a`, because it may be that `'a == 'b` and therefore the comparison borrows `self` for `'a`, so it is still borrowed immutably while we borrow it mutably for `some_mutable_fn()`.

Once we understood the problem, we can think about the solution. Either we require that `Pow` is covariant over `'a` (can be shrinked), or we require that it implements `PartialEq<Pow<'b>>` for any lifetime `'b`. The first is impossible in Rust, but the second is possible:

```rust
pub trait Pow<'a>: Clone + for<'b> PartialEq<<Self::R as Atom>::P<'b>> {
    type R: Atom;
}
```

This triggers an error, because the automatically-derived `PartialEq` does not satisfy this requirement:

```rust
error: implementation of `PartialEq` is not general enough
  --> src/main.rs:73:10
   |
73 | impl<'a> Pow<'a> for PowD<'a> {
   |          ^^^^^^^ implementation of `PartialEq` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `PartialEq<PowD<'0>>` would have to be implemented for the type `PowD<'a>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but `PartialEq` is actually implemented for the type `PowD<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

So we need to implement `PartialEq` manually:

```rust
impl<'a, 'b> PartialEq<PowD<'b>> for PowD<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &PowD<'b>) -> bool {
        self.data == other.data
    }
}
```

And now it works.